# v-on:select="myFunction" event is never fired

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to detect when the user selects some text on a specific element like a paragraph with VueJS. Other events are well handled but the onselect one not.

I've tried to use the onselect event, that is working in pure JS, but it seems VueJS cannot.

`<p @select="onSelectionChange" id="p1" class="card-text">{{ content }}</p>`

```
methods: {
        onSelectionChange(range) {
            console.log('selected');
        }
```

Comment: Try using @select.native=“onSelectionChange" and see if that works

Comment: @Tiger_Mike, he is not using a select dropdown/ input to register the change though. Its a paragraph tag

Comment: @FullStackEngineer Ah good point...missed that!

Comment: Vue does not have support for the text selection event. You will need to use a directive for it. There are many out there. [Here's one you can use](https://github.com/s010s/vue-text-selection)

Comment: @FullStackEngineer I already tried this and it wasn't working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you, I'll take a look !